# Problema con código de colas en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

Buen día, tengo un problema con un programa de colas en C. El problema está con el case 2, 3 y 5. Al ejecutar el case 2 o 3 (que consisten esencialmente en desencolar un elemento), y después querer mostrar todos los elementos que existen en la cola, se vuelven a mostrar todos los elementos, como si jamás se hubieran desencolado, he intentado de todo y no he podido hacer que funcione como corresponde, así que agradecería mucho su ayuda, pues apenas estoy introduciéndome en el tema de pilas y colas. Este es el código en cuestión:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
struct taqueria {

  char *tacos;
  struct taqueria *siguiente;
};

typedef struct taqueria Nodo;

Nodo *final=NULL;
Nodo *inicio=NULL;

char* getPtrNom();

int vacia();
int menu();
void clearBuffer();
void eliminarpedido();
void push();
void vacio();
void realizarpedido ();
void imprimir ();
void borrar ();
void contar ();
void mostrar_pedidos();

main() {
 return menu();
}

int menu() {
  char c;
  printf("\n -------------------------------------- \n");
  printf("               ~ TAQUERIA  ~");
  printf("\n -------------------------------------- \n");
  do {
  
    printf("\n ------- Menu------- \n");
    printf("\nHaga una seleccion:");
    printf("\n 1. Hacer pedido");
    printf("\n 2. Preparar pedido");
    printf("\n 3. Eliminar pedido");
    printf("\n 4. Verificar si existen pedidos pendientes");
    printf("\n 5. Mostrar todos los pedidos");
    printf("\n 6. Contar todos los pedidos");
    printf("\n q: Salir.\n");
    c = getchar();
    switch(c) {
      case '1':
         clearBuffer();
         push();
         break;
        case '2':
            clearBuffer();
            realizarpedido();
            break;  
        case '3':
         clearBuffer();
          eliminarpedido();
          break;
        case '4':
            clearBuffer();
            vacio();
            break;
        case '5':
            clearBuffer();
            mostrar_pedidos();
           break;
        case '6':
            clearBuffer();
            contar();
           break;
           default:
          break;
      
    }
  } while(c != 'q' && c != EOF);
  return 1;
}


void vacio() {
  clearBuffer();
  if (vacia()) {
    printf("\n----No hay pedidos pendientes----\n");
  } 
  else {
    printf("\n----Todavia hay pedidos pendientes----\n");
  }
}

char* getPtrNom() {
  char d,*newAr;

  int i = 0;

  newAr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

  printf("Ingrese su pedido: ");

  while((d = getchar()) != EOF && d != '\n') {
    newAr[i++] = d;
  }

  return newAr;
}


void eliminarpedido() {
  Nodo *actual, *temporal;
  clearBuffer();

  if (vacia()) {
    printf("\nNo hay pedidos que eliminar...\n");
  } else {
    if (final == inicio) { // si solo hay 1 nodo
    printf ("\nPedido eliminado con exito\n");
    printf ("\nEl unico pedido faltante es:\n");
      printf( "%s" , final->tacos);
      final = inicio = 0; 
    } 
    else { 
      actual = final;
      while (actual != inicio) { 
        temporal = actual; 
        actual = temporal->siguiente;
      }
      printf ("\nPedido eliminado con exito\n");
    printf ("\nPedidos faltantes:\n");
      inicio = temporal;
      return imprimir ();
    }
  }
}
void borrar (){
     Nodo *actual, *temporal;
  clearBuffer();

  if (vacia()) {
    printf("\nNo hay pedidos que eliminar...\n");
  } else {
    if (final == inicio) { // si solo hay 1 nodo
   
      printf("%s", final->tacos);
      final = inicio = 0; 
    } 
    else { 
      actual = final;
      while (actual != inicio) { 
        temporal = actual; 
        actual = temporal->siguiente;
      }
      inicio = temporal;
      return imprimir ();
    }
  }
    
}

void push(){
  Nodo *nodoNuevo;

  nodoNuevo = (Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  nodoNuevo->tacos = getPtrNom();
  nodoNuevo->siguiente=NULL;
  
  if (vacia()) { // si la cola esta vacia
    final = nodoNuevo; 
    inicio = nodoNuevo;
  } else { // si hay al menos 1 nodo
    inicio->siguiente=nodoNuevo;
    inicio = nodoNuevo; // apuntando al nodo que estaba en primer lugar
    
  }
   
}
void realizarpedido (){
    printf("\n[Realizando el pedido...]\n");
    printf("\n[Cocinando los ingredientes...]\n");
    printf("\n[Poniendo todo en la tortilla...]\n");
    printf("\n[Terminando la orden...]\n");
    printf("\n--------Pedido realizado--------\n");
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("\nActualizando lista de pedidos...\n");
    return borrar();


} 

void imprimir(void){
    
        if (NULL==inicio){
        printf ("No hay pedidos");
    } 
    else{
         Nodo *reco=inicio;
        printf("\n-------------Lista de pedidos-------------\n");
        while(reco != NULL){
            printf("\n                    %s         \n" , reco-> tacos);
            reco=reco->siguiente;
            reco=reco;
    }
        printf("\n -------Fin de la lista de pedidos------- \n");
    }
}
void mostrar_pedidos(void){
    
        if (NULL==inicio){
        printf ("No hay pedidos");
    } 
    else{
         Nodo *reco=final;
        printf("\n-------------Lista de pedidos-------------\n");
        while(reco != NULL){
            printf("\n                    %s         \n" , reco-> tacos);
            reco=reco->siguiente;
            reco=reco;
    }
        printf("\n -------Fin de la lista de pedidos------- \n");
    }
}

int vacia() {
  if (inicio == NULL) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void clearBuffer() {
  while(getchar() != '\n') ;
}
void contar(void){
    Nodo *nodo = inicio;
    int i=0;
    while (nodo != NULL){
        i++;
        nodo = nodo -> siguiente;
    }
    printf ("\n La cantidad de pedidos que hay es: %d\n" , i);
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push()` construye una lista encadenada al revés; es decir, el nuevo elemento  está puesto al principio de la lista (apuntado por `inicio`); el primer entrado está marcado por `final`. A menudo se llama LIFO o pila.

Si quieres que `borrar()` quite el elemento más antiguo, tienes que suprimir el elemento apuntado por `final` (`actual = final;` es correcto).
Luego para desencolar, el último elemento (el nuevo `final`) será él que está encadenado hasta `actual`; se consigue pasando por toda la lista:

```c
    temporal = inicio;
    while (temporal->siguiente!=actual)
        temporal = temporal->siguiente;
    final = temporal;
```

Sin embargo, es mucho más sencillo encadenar en orden directo, también llamado FIFO o cola. Se hace poniendo en `push()`:

```c
    final->siguiente = nodoNuevo;
    final = nodoNuevo; // pone el nuevo pedido al final de la cola
```

Y `borrar()` cambia a

```c
    actual = inicio; // pedido más antiguo de la cola
    inicio = inicio->siguiente; // se quita de la cola
```